# cpp-netlib complains about missing lboost-thread

Tags: c++, makefile, linker-errors, cpp-netlib

I'm learning cpp-netlib and I tried running the exmaple client given on the official website. The code is very simple:

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using namespace boost::network;

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [url]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    http::client client;
    http::client::request request(argv[1]);
    request << header("Connection", "close");
    http::client::response response = client.get(request);
    std::cout << body(response) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my makefile for this c++ application:
    CC = g++ -std=c++11

```
CFLAG = -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/include
LIBFLAG = -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/lib  

all: client

client: client.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAG) -lboost_system -lboost_thread client.o -o client  

client.o: client.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAG) client.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o client
```

It complains about not finding lboost_thread  library after compilation:

```
ld: library not found for -lboost_thread
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [client] Error 1
```

In my boost library directory, the boost_thread library shows up like this:

```
libboost_thread-mt.a      libboost_thread-mt.dylib
```

Why isn't it able to find this library? Did I make any mistake in the linking?

Comment: Try using -lboost_thread-mt  in place of -lboost_thread option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your makefile to link to -lboost-thread-mt instead of -lboost-thread.

You seems to be missing libboost_thread for some reason